# How to know under what filesystem /etc comes?

Tags: data-recovery, etc, deleted-files

I have accidentally deleted some important files of ldap server. Now I am trying to recover all these files. I tried [this post](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-ext3-ext4-deleted-files-recovery-howto.html) and ran these commands:

```
# mount
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00 on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol02 on /home type ext4 (rw)
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol01 on /opt type ext4 (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /root/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev)
# pwd
/etc/openldap/slapd.d
# debugfs -w /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol01
debugfs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
debugfs:  lsdel
 Inode  Owner  Mode    Size      Blocks   Time deleted
0 deleted inodes found.
debugfs:  #
#  debugfs -w /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
debugfs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
debugfs:  lsdel
 Inode  Owner  Mode    Size      Blocks   Time deleted
0 deleted inodes found.
```

But every time I got 0 deleted node found. Can anyone tell me under what file system `/etc` comes or how to go to this directory `/etc/openldap/slapd.d` so that I can recover the files?

Comment: Just restore from backup (or fire your sysadmin as incompetent if he hasn't made backups).

Answer (score 3):

Using the `df` utility you should be able to see on what filesystem a directory is seated, for example:

```
df -h /etc
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/crypt--lvm-root  225G  165G   50G  77% /
```

Note the input as `/etc` and the listed output `/` in column *"Mounted on"*

Comment: again getting 0 deleted node found so its not possible to recover deleted file now?

Comment: If your host is not rebooted yet, you might have the chance that the file is still opened by another process. Try `lsof|egrep "COMMAND|deleted"` to list those files. If your file is listed you can copy it from the open file descriptor of the process holding the handle using: `cp /proc/<PID>/fd/<FD>` where PID and FD are the values from the corresponding columns in the `lsof` output

Comment: @Lamert the above command even not showing file deleted from openldap its showing other deleted file

Comment: Have you tried `extundelete`? Please read the page http://edunham.net/2015/03/02/the_magic_of_extundelete.html for a use case.